# Convinced of something/somebody

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

We can felicitously say:

> I am upset with **your performance**.

And a related idea like this:

> I am upset with **you**.

---

Similarly, we can say:

> I am disappointed **with your performance**.

And again, similarly:

> I am disappointed **with you**.

---

My question is that while I know we can say:

> I am not convinced of **your ability**.

I think we can't say:

> I am not convinced of **you**.

Why are the above items all ok, but this one is not? And if it is not, how can we state that we are convinced of someone's ability in a similar form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the meaning of *convinced.*

To be convinced means to believe something is true or not true. It does not normally make sense to say something like *I am convinced that Subrat is true.*

It would be more common and natural to say *I'm confident in Subrat.*

It would probably work fairly well, more commonly in informal speech than in formal speech or in writing, to say *I'm convinced about Subrat* in certain contexts; for example:

> I'm certain of Anaya's ability. I'm pretty sure about Raj's. I'm very sure about Arjun's. I'm not convinced on/about Subrat.

Note that if the above was said, it would be understood to contain an implicit more complete noun phrase: *I'm not convinced about Subrat* meaning about Subrat's ability.

This could be made more conventional or formal like this:

> I'm not convinced about Subrat's.

It makes sense because it is Subrat's *ability* that we are convinced about or not. (Convinced that it is true or not true that Subrat has the ability to do something.)

Answer (score 0):

The verb **convince** can be used in the *active voice* or the *passive voice*.

In the *active voice* it takes a direct object.

> John convinced Mary (that she should take a coat with her)

In the *passive voice* it may be followed by a preposition, an adverb or a conjunction (and possibly something else that hasn't occurred to me).

> Mary was convinced **by** John to take a coat with her (preposition).
>
> Mary was convinced **of** your sincerity (but NOT convinced OF YOU) (preposition).
>
> Mary was convinced **after** she had listened to John (conjunction).
>
> Mary was convinced **that** John was correct (conjunction).
>
> Mary was convinced **quickly** (adverb)

Although **upset** and **disappointed** also express human emotions, they take their own particular prepositions. Don't expect consistency.